# Running paraview python through commandline

Tags: paraview

Is there any way to run a python script of paraview using command line.
right now I can open the file in "python shell" in paraview and get results. I am not able to figure out away to run it through commandline. Can you please tell me the syntax of running it.

```
import os
i=0
SubDir = [" "]*30
# Set the directory you want to start from
rootDir = '/var/www/html/php/emd/job552e23fe74d102/VTK'
for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(rootDir):
    if dirName == rootDir + '/others':
       continue
    if dirName == rootDir:
       continue
    SubDir.append(dirName)
    i=i+1
    print('Found directory: %s' % dirName)
    for fname in fileList:
        print('\t%s' % fname)
        j=1
        j= LegacyVTKReader( FileNames=[dirName + '/' + fname] )
```

This my code

Answer (score 0):

You should call the script with pvpython from the bin.

```
pvpython /dir/script.py
```

- Make sure to utilize the gui Trace options in the ParaView Python shell to make sure your code is correct before running it.